# Can Systemd service(installed bg service) access the file data from hard drive of Linux machine?

Tags: linux, files, systemd

I have a `systemd` service(background service) to install in Linux machine. Service is responsible for sending mails to multiple users.

I have a text file in hard drive(directory) of Linux machine which has list of email addresss and everyday this list of users is getting changed.

Just I want to know if the service can read data from file which available in the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just I want to know if the service can read data from file which available in the same machine?

If the file that contains a list of email addresses is readable by the user that the service is run as, then there is no reason why the service would not have access to the list of email addresses.

Comment: You mean to say that it will read data.

Comment: Reading the data is the job of the process (e.g. programming). There are lots of ways of feeding info to your process. If it consumes STDIN you might be able to pipe it into your process, if it takes file args, then you could do that.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya if you are waning more help, i suggest updating your question with the service's systemd service file and provide a description the process / command.

Comment: Sure, I will do that. Once I get my things ready.